# What set is the safari car in the 2020 catalogue from?

Tags: set-identification, city

On page 2 of the (German version of the) 2020 January-July Lego catalogue, there is a promotional image with various sets or parts thereof<sup>1</sup>.

[image]

[Catalogue online version](https://catalogs.lego.com/BrandCatalog/1hy2020/de/bc-1hy-2020-dea/?page=2).

In the lower right corner of that image, we can see a nice-looking safari car with a puma and a photographer disguised as a tree and a colourful parrot on top. I could not find this car anywhere in the catalogue.

**Is it from a set? Is it something that was planned to be released, but eventually wasn't, maybe when promotional materials had already been prepared? Or is it a teaser image for an upcoming 2020/2 set?**

---

<sup>1</sup>: For instance, I can recognize the train from [10874](https://brickset.com/sets/10874-1/Steam-Train), the [31105 toy store](https://brickset.com/sets/31105-1/Townhouse-Toy-Store), the tent and campfire (glampfire?) from [41392](https://brickset.com/sets/41392-1/Nature-Glamping), the police plane from [60210](https://brickset.com/sets/60210-1/Air-Base), and the top half of [71712](https://brickset.com/sets/71712-1/Empire-Temple-of-Madness).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a new [60267](https://brickset.com/sets/60267-1/Safari-Off-Roader) set to be released this year under City theme:

[image]

Comment: Nice! Curious that it's not listed in the catalogue.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I suspect set might be LEGO store exclusive.

Comment: @Alex it’s in stores here in NZ.